# Style DataTrigger not evaluating on initial load

Tags: c#, wpf

Title says it all

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="level1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock x:Name="GroupTitle" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF000532" Text="{Binding name}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="GroupDescription" Text="{Binding description}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Depth" Text="{Binding childDepth}"/>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding settings}">

            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="level2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock x:Name="GroupTitle" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF000532" Text="{Binding name}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="GroupDescription" Text="{Binding description}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Depth" Text="{Binding childDepth}"/>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding settings}">

            </ItemsControl>
            <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding groups}">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource level1}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl x:Name="SettingsDisplayer" Content="{Binding settingGroup, ElementName=page}">
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource level1}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=childDepth}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource level1}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=childDepth}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource level2}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=childDepth}" Value="3">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource level3}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=childDepth}" Value="4">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource level4}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

The getter for `childDepth` is not even being accessed because I put a console trace in there to know when it is. The property is populated as it shows the proper amount when seen in the Depth `TextBlock` in the `DataTemplate`s.

The relevant property in my class:

```
    public int childDepth { get { Console.WriteLine(this.getDepth()); return this.getDepth(); } }
```

No mater what the childDepth is it alwayse skipps the triggers and just uses the level1 template.

Comment: It looks like you have an xml file with more than one root tag.  XML usually has only one root tag so your xml is a fragment.  You could wrap the xml data in to a single root tag using a string method() : <root>your current xml</root>.  string myString = "<root>" + xml + "</root>";

Comment: @jdweng What? no I dont. That wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel silly, So apparently binding the `ContentControl`'s Content is not the equivalent of binding data to the `ContentControl`, thus I needed to target my DataTrigger Bindings more specifically at my original DP since it doesn't just take the parent containers binding.

This worked:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding settingGroup.childDepth, ElementName=page}" Value="1">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource level1}" />
</DataTrigger>
```